# Where can I find all the functions?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Recently, I was adding some transition in activities. Some common transitions can be found in internet (I was looking for heart shaped transition which I found in kinemaster. And there's more which isn't directly available in internet). But all kind of transition isn't available (who will be interested to write tons of transitioning questions in SO?). So I was thinking that the Android Studio guidance  might give information of all the functions. So I was looking at developer. I found [some](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/ref/transition) documentation but it doesn't contain lots of information. I recently found the following code.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <explode
        android:duration="320" />
</transitionSet>
```

I didn't know that there was a function called `explode`. There might be more function like that but where can I find all the functions? Is there any kind of documentation which contains all the functions?

Comment: After searching more, I found this: https://github.com/android/animation-samples still not good enough.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition "Known direct subclasses
ChangeBounds, ChangeClipBounds, ChangeImageTransform, ChangeScroll, ChangeTransform, TransitionSet, Visibility"
"Known indirect subclasses
AutoTransition, Explode, Fade, Slide"